# Basis of natural logarithm raised to a power

Tags: summation, logarithms

So the basis of the natural logarithm is this:

$$\large e = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac1{n!}$$

Starting from that, how can we get to:
$$\large e^x = 1 + \frac{x}{1!} + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \cdots = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

So, how can we raise the right hand side from the first equation to the power `x` and get the right hand side from the second equation?

Comment: We can't go that way, since $e$ is just a special case of $e^x$ (with $x=1$). One usually takes your second equation as a definition of $e^x$.

Comment: Please read this:
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Lovsovs so from LHS1 to LHS2 we can get by raising to power `x`. If we raise RHS1 to power `x`, how can we get to RHS2?

Comment: You can't is what I'm saying. The raising to the power of $x$ doesn't distribute over the terms of the sum, so you can only say that you raise what the sum evaluates to (which is $e$) to the power of $x$. The reason why you can't go from RHS1 to RHS2 is because RHS2 is because 2 is more general than 1. It is like saying: "$f(1)=1,$ now how can I deduce that $f(x)=x$?" You can't, $f(x)$ could be lots of other things.

Comment: @Lovsovs I would say the second equation is the definition of $\exp(x)$ rather than of $e^x$.  It is then reasonable to ask why $\exp(x)=(\exp(1))^x$ is true

Comment: @Henry I've never heard anyone say $\exp(x)$ is something different than $e^x$. What is the distinction?

Comment: @Lovsovs One is a function either defined as a series as here or defined as the limit of $(1+x/n)^n$ as $n \to \infty$ or defined as the solution to as $f'(x)=f(x)$ with $f(0)=1$, while the other is a real number raised to a power.  The proof that they are equal usually shows that the function satisfies $\exp(x+y) =\exp(x)\exp(y)$

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by defining the function $$\exp(x)=1+\frac{x}{1!}+\cdots+\frac{x^n}{n!}+\cdots = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

We can say

- $\exp(x)$ is absolutely convergent by considering the sums of terms where $n \gt |x|$
- $\exp(x)$ is monotonic increasing for $x\ge 0$
- $\exp(0)=1$
- $2 \lt \exp(1) \lt 3$.  Let's define $e=\exp(1)$
- $\exp(x)\exp(y)=\exp(x+y)$ since $\left(1+\frac{x}{1!}+\cdots+\frac{x^n}{n!}+\cdots \right)\left(1+\frac{y}{1!}+\cdots+\frac{y^m}{m!}+\cdots \right)$ $=1 + \frac{x}{1!}+\frac{y}{1!}+\cdots + \binom{n+m}{n}\frac{x^ny^m}{(n+m)!}+\cdots$ $=1+\frac{x+y}{1!}+\cdots+\frac{(x+y)^{n+m}}{(n+m)!}+\cdots$
- $\exp(-x) = \frac1{\exp(x)}$ since $\exp(-x)\exp(x)=\exp(0)=1$
- $\exp(nx) = (\exp(x))^n$ for integer $n$ and in particular $\exp(n) = e^n$
- $\exp(x/m) = (\exp(x))^(1/m)$ for positive integer $m$ and in particular $\exp(1/m) = e^{1/m}$
- $\exp(n/m) = e^{n/m}$
- $\exp(x)$ is continuous
- $\exp(x) = e^x$ moving from the rational to the reals